# Unable to open sidebar when I click on Hamburger button

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have got two components named header and navbar.
I have got a navbar in navbar.component.html which I want to display on my screen when I click on the hamburger button in header.component.html
Both the components have AppComponent as parent component

My plan is to transfer a flag(boolean) value from childComponent(header) to appComponent(Parent) and then transfer the same flag value from appComponent(parent) to navbarComponent(another child)

What I have done till now:

In the header.component.html, I have put a click event which fires the function toggleSidebar() in header.component.ts where the flag is emitted from child(itself) to parent(appComponent).

Now I am confused as to how to fire another function inside navbarComponent which is also called toggleSidebar() with the flag value, i.e. I want to pass the flag in a function and fire it from parent(appComponent) to child(navbarComponent)

P.S. I am new to angular, any help would be appreciated.

Link to code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd4wvm

Comment: share your code or stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd4wvm

Comment: There was a small glitch in stackblitz that you mentioned, here is the corrected one. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ri1ths (Does not answer the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updated [stackblitz](https://angular-fz4yub.stackblitz.io).

I have removed the input and output property from header and `navbar` component; instead of this I have used Subject from `rxjs` for communication.

For this I have simply created a Service viz. `AppService`, and in that I have implemented the Subject using variable `flagChange`.

From header file when ever user clicks on hamburger icon, toggle function is called which calls app service, in that I pass the change Value to `flagChange`.

Then in `navbar` component, I have injected app service object and using it I have subscribed(observed) the `flagChange` value in `ngInit()`.

So when the user clicks on icon, flag value in header component gets toggled, this change is registered/given to `flagChange` variable in `AppService` using next() function and this change is observed using subscribe method in `navbar` component.